# does "make" recompile all of the files or just changed ones

Tags: compiling, make, makefile, configure, autoconf

suppose that you have a program which you installed that from source by `make` command . That program include files  **a.cc**, **b.cc**, **c.cc**, **d.cc** and ... .

Now I changed **a.cc** a bit. In order to enable the changes I should **compile** the program again by `make` command.

**My question**: Is `make` command just recompile the changed files or recompile all of the files.

ps :all of the files are define on as .o on the Makefile.

Comment: I *think* if you have something like `*.o` as a target, then it will act as an incremental compiler.

Comment: you mean make compile all of them and by *.o we can tell make to compile which file exactly?

Comment: Edit: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663626/make-and-incremental-builds#comment10766995_8663675) comment and the corresponding answer. In the case of that answer, if you run `make result`, it should do an incremental build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general way, You don't need recompile all of .cc files according to modify a .cc file.

The a `.cc` file is related with other `.cc` by using `.h` file.

For example:

Let's guess `b.h` is a header about `b.cc`.

And `a.cc` use `b.h`.

You don't need *recompile* `a.cc` due to *modify* and *compile* `b.cc`.

But You need to *recompile* about `b.h`.

If the `makefile` is created as well(based on `autotools`), `make` command will process the dependencies as well.

Comment: thanks, you mean that is based on the "how is the Makefile creat for this program?" so is there any way to guess, if my Makefile recompile all of them or just the changed ones?

Comment: You can use automake, autoconf, configure...  Then Makefile is created as optimized for compile just ones must compile.

Comment: is ./configure is enough ? I installed automake and autoconf before.

Comment: I am using anjuta to use autotools. If you create Makefile from scratch, I suggest you use developing tools like anjuta.